# Exercise to determine source code behaviour using strace

Tags: c, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04, system-calls

I have an assignment where I am given an x86 Linux executable and am supposed to explain the reason why the strace appears as follows. This is what happens where I run strace -f in Ubuntu 16.04.5 on VirtualBox.

```
execve("./asg-myst", ["./asg-myst"], [/* 67 vars */]) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="student-VirtualBox", ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1191000
brk(0x11921c0)                          = 0x11921c0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x1191880)      = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/home/student/Desktop/asgUBUNTU"..., 4096) = 42
brk(0x11b31c0)                          = 0x11b31c0
brk(0x11b4000)                          = 0x11b4000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2246, ...}) = 0
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 2246
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
write(1, "csdae+", 6)                   = 6
getpid()                                = 3794
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x1191b50) = 3795
wait4(-1, strace: Process 3795 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid  3795] write(1, "795794=", 7)      = 7
[pid  3795] lseek(3, -2167, SEEK_CUR)   = 79
[pid  3795] exit_group(42)              = ?
[pid  3795] +++ exited with 42 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 42}], 0, NULL) = 3795
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3795, si_uid=1000, si_status=42, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
write(1, "42\n", 3)                     = 3
lseek(3, -2167, SEEK_CUR)               = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My description will be this:

The parent process calls getpid() system call, then the parent calls clone(). This somehow stores the getpid value of the parent process into the child process, without the child process calling getpid() to return the parent’s pid value. This is evident in the strace of the code, running with an additional -f flag.

Since the program is always run as a new process, the pid value is always changing.
The printed output has a pattern of 6 digits which is related to the changing pid value, where the rightmost 3 digits corresponds to the rightmost 3 digit of the getpid() of the parent, and the leftmost 3 digits that remains is this rightmost 3 digits previously +1. For example, for a pid of 3287, last 3 digits is 287, so the printed output is 288287.

The child process exit_group(42) which somehow edits the si_status, and the parent process prints this si_status before exiting normally.

> Is there something I’m lacking in my analysis, I’m just thinking this is the flow solely by reading the strace output.

Comment: Read the section about shared resources in the documentation of `clone`. This should explain the behavior of the `lseek` calls in child and parent. Check the delayed `wait4` system call and see the exit status `42` there.

Comment: Even if this question were on topic, we couldn't effectively evaluate your analysis without a more specific description of the assignment than "explain the reason the strace appears as follows".  If I were to guess, however, I would suppose that the instructor was looking for something more along the lines of a possible sequence of C function calls in the program source that would produce such a trace.  If you choose to look into that, then consider trying to duplicate the trace with a program you write yourself as a means to check your analysis.